# Declare an array in Fortran with the name of a parameter in another module

Tags: arrays, fortran

I'm pretty new in the Fortran world. I get a piece of code, where I find difficulty in understanding it.

Let's say in module A, `var` is declared as a parameter of integer type:

```
integer, parameter :: var = 81
```

Then in another module B, an array with the name `var` is declared:

```
integer :: var(2)
```

When these modules are used in a third module C:

```
use A
use B
```

Won't there be conflict in the names? Or the two members of the array `var` will take the value 81?

Answer (score 8):

There will be a compile time error when you attempt to access the variable `var` in your described case.  The specific error will look like:

```
Error: Name 'var' at (1) is an ambiguous reference to 'var' from module 'a'
```

Are those variables meant to be globally scoped?  You can declare one (or both) of them with `private` so they are scoped to the module and do not pollute the global scope.  In this case though, module C would not be able to use the private variable.  Another option is to limit what is imported in your `use` statement with:

```
use A, only: some_variable1, some_other_variable
use B, only: var
```

This would let `var` from B into the scope of C, and would hide `var` from A.

If you have to have both variables in module C, you can rename one when you use the module. E.g.:

```
use A, varA => var
use B, varB => var
```

which lets you access the variables var in each module by the names `varA` and `varB`.

See this example:

```
module A
  integer, parameter :: var = 81
 contains
end module

module B
  integer :: var(2)
 contains
end module

module C
  use A, varA => var
  use B, varB => var
 contains
end module

program test
  use C    
  print *, varA
end program
```

which will print `81`.

Comment: Or (one) `var` can be renamed on the `use` statement.

Comment: strange that Fortran does not allow one use the module name as scope name, so one could have written `A::var` or `A->var` or `A.var` whatever the right syntax would be. having to rename things all the time does not seem like a good way to go about these things. This problem have been solved long time ago by Ada for example with its package system.